# Basic steps for creating very simple CMS system for ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, content-management-system

I am working on an `ASP.NET MVC 4` application, that has admin panel, which purpose is to offer very basic CMS functionality. What I need is to provide ability for the admins to create new layouts and new pages using those layouts and filling them with content.

Using an existing CMS is not an option (don't know why), I never had to implement such a thing and I'm not able to find any tutorials, articles about this topic.

Can you provide some basic logic, or good tutorial on how to build such a basic functionality, it seems like a general question but still the idea is to work for `ASP.NET MVC 4`.

Comment: You may want to be aware that questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: You may want to be aware that this question is not asking for code - `Can you provide some basic logic, or good tutorial`. The very fact that got 11 views for under a minute may tell you that it's getting attention of other users except me. Maybe there is a reason for that..

Comment: @Leron, this close reason would have been more appropos, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  Bottom line -- still off topic.

Comment: My apologies for the misunderstanding.  "basic logic" sounded like code to me. :)

Comment: @Kirk Woll I recognize my question only in `favorite off-site resources` but still, my question is not "Which is the best way to make this", but "Any way to create this" since I'm stuck. You may find many questions here in `SO` where there are off-site resources.

Comment: @paqogomez What I mean by `basic logic` is - you need this so you can make this, then make that, and that's the basic logic behind any simple CMS. Don't feel obligated to provide code if you don't want/have, I'll be more than happy with just the logic, I can do the coding myself.

Comment: @paqogomez sure, pal, I'll copy-paste it for you - `What I need is to provide ability for the admins to create new layouts and new pages using those layouts and filling them with content.` - as far as functionality goes. And the steps are as basic as your knowledge is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a basic one for my clients, i set up a seperate area (backend). With a basic authentication system using a flat file database (so no dependency on MS SQL or something). I used [Biggy](https://github.com/xivSolutions/biggy) for this

I used bootstrap as layout.

Added a drop-zone file uploader (for images)

Added a slider which pics the images, people could order this

GUI is markdown or a basic HTML wysiwyg editor

Packed it into a nuget package and saved it on a Nuget RSS feeds so i could easily load it into an existing package.

Comment: Fixed, the project seems to have moved

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget, i just found out about these CMS projects (both opensource)

- [BetterCMS](http://www.bettercms.com/)
- [Ecms](http://mvceasycms.ism-ukraine.com/)

Answer (score 4):

If I were you I would take a look at some open source examples out there for comparison and decide which features you want to implement and how they accomplish them. There are a few examples I found when searching:

[Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) - An open source ASP.NET MVC based CMS that is highly rated.

[OSNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osnetcms/) - Open Source ASP.NET CMS found on SourceForge.

In addition [this article](http://abundantcode.com/15-best-asp-net-based-content-management-systemscms/) has some good resources that you might find useful (scroll to the bottom for implementation specific details). Just do a little research on it before giving up, most of this stuff isn't hard to find and it's almost certainly been done before.